# How should I intercept the main query and inject custom join / order by / group by criteria

Tags: query-posts, hooks, loop, sql

I have a CPT that is a member of two separate taxonomies. On the taxonomy archive page for one of the taxonomies, I need to further group and sort on the second taxonomy like so:

mysite.com/tax1/term1/

tax2-term1
-post
-post
-post
[see more]

tax2-term2
-post
-post
-post
[see more]

... etc.

### Better Example

To provide a more easily accessible example, consider the following CPT: Toys. And the two taxonomies: Colour and Age Group.

On the taxonomy archive page for mysite.com/colour/red, I need to further group on the second taxonomy, "age group" like so:

**Red Toys**

Ages: 0 - 12 months
-toy
-toy
-toy
[see more Red toys for ages 0 - 12 mo]

Ages: 12-24 months
-toy
-toy
-toy
[see more Red toys for ages 12 - 24 mo]

etc...

## Intercepting query_posts

So, unless I'm mistaken and we've suddenly got the ability to sort on taxonomy (grouping would be ideal, but I could work around that), I'm thinking that a custom SQL query with my own tax joins will be the best way to get what I need. Correct me if I'm wrong. Most of the time I want to go the built-in WP way, I just don't see that working here.

How would you hijack the main query to still use The_Loop(TM) but with custom SQL? Or would you find a way to return an empty query and then just roll your own custom SQL loop?

Right now I'm leaning toward using `pre_get_posts` to set up a `posts_clauses` replacement of the join, groupby, orderby and maybe limits clauses, or even a wholesale replacement of the entire request using `posts_request`.

Is there an easier way?

Comment: Have you looked at `tax_query` for `WP_Query`?

Comment: +1 for a fun read. @m0r7if3r He wants a one tax query and then sort by the 2nd taxonomy terms.

Comment: @kaiser Yea, I was just having a hard time understanding what exactly was trying to be done...the way I read it, it was within `tax_query`'s capabilities, and I was hoping he'd report back that that did it, and if not, how that fails to meet his needs. I think your answer got it though.

Comment: @m0r7if3r Hopefully I got a _little_ closer. Pretty shure that it's not the actual solution. Just yesterday mod told me that it's a bad habbit to answer Qs like that (guessing and asking). :)

Answer (score 1):

*If* I understood you right...

- **[A]** Multi-Tax queries have the problem that they're doing a `JOIN` of the meta table for every term. So imho it's not the best idea to use the built in way.
- **[B.1.a]** I'd simply do a normal query with a one (main-)tax arg and then do the sorting depending on the meta values. So actually just calling `get_post_custom()` and merging it with a single post object during a loop and then appending it to a resulting array.
- **[B.1.b]** Then modifying the query through `posts_clauses` if some bits doesn't meet the requirements.
- **[B.2]** Start sorting for e.g. by name.
- **[B.3]** Then I'd go and run some foreach/etc loop on the resulting array.

The benefit of browser/php vs. DB isn't there so far (as long as the site hasn't got much hits). But if you start minifying css/js/html and caching the resulting stuff (and delivering the results from the hard disk), I think this would be the way I'd go.